# Firebase authentication is failing behind a proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, proxy, firebase-authentication

I have an Express server that is pushing some data on my Firebase database.
This server is hosted on an intranet, and thus is behind a proxy. I've set the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables, so it is able to connect to the Internet.

Instead of the Express server, just consider a basic nodeJs snippet.

When I try to read the data, it works (the Firebase database is configured to allow a read right on anyone, including anonymous users):

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
function test() {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'xxx',
    authDomain: 'xxx.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com',
    storageBucket: ''
  });
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(currentUser => {
    console.log('USER IS => ', currentUser);
  });
  firebase.database().ref('configuration').once('value', data => {
    console.log('GOT: ', data.val());
  });
}
test();
```

The output of this code is:

```
USER IS => null  // OK, since I didn't authenticate
GOT: { 'foo': 'bar' }     // I got correct data from the database
```

Now, I add authentication mechanism before requesting data:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
function test() {
  firebase.initializeApp({...});
  firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(err => {
    console.log('ERROR !', err);
  });
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(currentUser => {
    console.log('USER IS => ', currentUser);
  });
  firebase.database().ref('configuration').once('value', data => {
    console.log('GOT: ', data.val());
  });
}
test();
```

The output is:

```
USER IS => null
ERROR ! { [Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.]
  code: 'auth/network-request-failed',
  message: 'A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.' }
GOT: { 'foo': 'bar' }
```

The same happens with an email/password authentication (`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('a@example.com', 'foobar')`).

So from what I can see, the node code is able to reach the firebase (since I can retrieve the data), but the authentication is not able to achieve.

I've also made a test to put that code in a HTML page, using firebase.js library. In that case, I have no problem to authenticate (which means that some authentication URL, such as googleapis.com, are not blocked by my entreprise proxy).

Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: The node.js auth module depends on npm package xmlhttprequest for http requests.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest
Can you try to use that module directly to make http requests and isolate the cause of this issue?